# Short Domain Name

Tags: aws-acm

I can create a public certificate with name *.srdr.trade in ACM. But while trying to obtain a certificate with name *.trade, this gives an error invalid domain name. is there any way that I can obtain this kind of certificate, any work around possible? actually i want to use below domain names with https.

```
srdr.trade  
dev.srdr.trade  
stage.srdr.trade
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, If I put below two in ACM dns name, that works for me.

```
*.srdr.trade
srdr.trade
```